# Pandas dataframe Apply very slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am trying add a binary variable that tells whether a product was in the last order and the order before that etc. for the the last 5 orders. I came up with the following pandas dataframe expression. It does exactly what it is supposed to do , but it it extruciatingly slow. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my dataframe:

```
order_id    user_id order_number    product_id  us_last_order_number
2539329 1   1   196 10
2539329 1   1   14084   10
2539329 1   1   12427   10
2539329 1   1   26088   10
2539329 1   1   26405   10
2398795 1   2   196 10
2398795 1   2   10258   10
2398795 1   2   12427   10
2398795 1   2   13176   10
2398795 1   2   26088   10
2398795 1   2   13032   10
473747  1   3   196 10
473747  1   3   12427   10
473747  1   3   10258   10
473747  1   3   25133   10
473747  1   3   30450   10
2254736 1   4   196 10
2254736 1   4   12427   10
2254736 1   4   10258   10
2254736 1   4   25133   10
2254736 1   4   26405   10
431534  1   5   196 10
431534  1   5   12427   10
431534  1   5   10258   10
431534  1   5   25133   10
431534  1   5   10326   10
431534  1   5   17122   10
431534  1   5   41787   10
431534  1   5   13176   10
3367565 1   6   196 10



tmp2 =  priors_orders_detail.groupby(['user_id', 
                    'product_id']).apply(lambda x: [1 if item in x.order_number.tolist() else -1 if item<0 else 0 for item in range(x.us_last_order_number.iloc[0],x.us_last_order_number.iloc[0]-5,-1)])

tmp2= pd.DataFrame(tmp2).reset_index()

tmp2.columns.values[-1]='present_in_orders' tmp2[['in_orders_1','in_orders_2',
      'in_orders_3','in_orders_4',
      'in_orders_5']] = pd.DataFrame([x for x in tmp2.present_in_orders]) tmp2.drop('present_in_orders',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: I dont understand the entire problem... can you be a bit more clear... user_id as 1 and product_id as 196 are present in all the five orders but the output has all 0's for first four columns created and in_orders_5 is 1. Can you explain a bit about us_last_order_number.?

Comment: Can you add a sample of what you'd like to see, i.e. the result you wanted?